# get value from ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am trying to get value of clicked child of this list and put it as key-value pair. But after execution of this:

```
expandableListView
                .setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(
                            ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                            int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                            long id) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), NumerekActivity.class);
View child_view =  placowkaGrupaAdapter.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, false, v, parent);
i.putExtra("key", child_view.toString());
```

**I got an error:**
I am trying to get value of clicked child of this list and put it as key-value pair. But after execution of above I got an error.

> 02-12 23:07:38.869 15940-15940/net.dbcoder.kolejka.android
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: net.dbcoder.kolejka.android, PID: 15940
>                                                                                java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 5, size is 0
>                                                                                    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                    at
>   net.dbcoder.kolejka.android.adapters.PlacowkaGrupaAdapter.getChild(PlacowkaGrupaAdapter.java:62)
>                                                                                    at
>   net.dbcoder.kolejka.android.adapters.PlacowkaGrupaAdapter.getChildView(PlacowkaGrupaAdapter.java:95)
>                                                                                    at
>   net.dbcoder.kolejka.android.listaPlacowek$2.onChildClick(listaPlacowek.java:93)

Is it good way at all ? How to operate on this ?

adapter class

```
public class PlacowkaGrupaAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<String> header_titles;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> child_items;
    private Context ctx;

    public PlacowkaGrupaAdapter(PlacowkaGrupa[] placowkaGrupas, Context ctx) {
        List<String> header_titles = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String,List<String>> child_items = new HashMap<>();


        for (PlacowkaGrupa placowkaGrupa : placowkaGrupas){
            header_titles.add(placowkaGrupa.getPlacowka().getNazwa_placowki());
            child_items.put(placowkaGrupa.getPlacowka().getNazwa_placowki(),placowkaGrupa.getNazwa_grupy());
        }
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.header_titles = header_titles;
        this.child_items = child_items;

    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return header_titles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child_items.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return header_titles.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child_items.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String)this.getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.headliny,null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_item);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setText(title);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String) this.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chilitemy,null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_item);
        textView.setText(title);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

values for groupPosition,childPosition are proper I tested it via display those values in another activity and they matched my selections in list.So only thing is how to proper call adapter method or get this selected values somehow.

adapter is declared with blank set of objects but loader add them and list which is displayed is really fine. Maybe those two things are separated I mean display thing and underlying values .... I am confused here.

```
placowkaGrupaAdapter = new PlacowkaGrupaAdapter(new PlacowkaGrupa[]{},this);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(placowkaGrupaAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your log it seems that placowkaGrupaAdapter doesn't have any child views at all. (Invalid index 5, size is 0)

I would suggest making sure that all of the initialisations for the adapter are carried out before this occurs.

Also, it seems to me from this small segment of code that you can simply use the View view function parameter.

If you were to provide more of the code or elaborate on the purpose of this code I would be happy to help.

However these are the suggestions I can give based on this code.

Comment: I added adapter class and comments. Please take a look.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the method you should call is:
`View child_view =  (View)placowkaGrupaAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);`

Comment: unfortunately the same thing happened:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index ...`

Comment: Perhaps you should go about it differently, I would suggest in the getChildView method of the adapter to add: <br> `convertView.setOnClickListener(new ...)`<br> This way you can get at all the data in the view and get the same functionality.

Comment: but Intent related functionallity seems to work differently here. Can you provide some code example how you manage it ?

Comment: You can use the intent with no problem:
`public void onClick(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), NumerekActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key", view.toString());
view.getContext().startActivity(i);}` 
Will get you the same functionality.